# Copy Selected Data from DataGridView to another one when DataGridView is bounded

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a small issue and I am trying to solve this problem a long time ago.
My problem is that i would like to copy a Selected DATA from a DataGridView to another but these DataGridViews are bounded.
Thanks For Helping
IF you need help just send my a message.
Thank Romeo

Comment: I the DataGridViews bounded, you should detect which row(s) are currently selected then take that data and copy to the datasource, to which the second DataGridView is bound.

Comment: I know the way I have problem with the code

Comment: You could use a pair of views which filter the rows on a bool column.  No copying required

Comment: I need a code not a Solution.
Can you pls help me with this

Comment: To provide you some code please provide some of your existing code here.

Answer (score 0):

Then you copy from Selected DataGridView to DataSource of DataGridView you want to copy too.

Comment: Yeah Thank for this I know the method the problem is that i dont know the code